# Using a SQL Table instead of a Dictionary Reference in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio

Right now I have all of my data that I need for my program stored in a separate class `Tool` and within that class their is a `Dictionary<int, string> myTools`. I have heard that for future use, it would be better to store this in a table within an SQL Database.

*Here's what I have now:*

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> myTools = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
    {1001, "Tool 1"},
    {1002, "Tool 2"},
    {1003, "Tool 3"},
    //...and so on...
}
```

With this in my program, I am able to reference the integer associated and the output the string "name" that is attached with that integer using something like this: `Tool.myTools[1002]`. I like this method because I can easily change up the names of the tools without having to change the way they are called. However, I would like to ultimately control the tool names for multiple programs all through one database, and that is why I am looking to essentially copy this Dictionary class over to a SQL server. I think this is done in the form of a single table, but I am BARELY experienced with SQL Server Management Studio, and that is why I am coming here for help.

**What I want to know:** How can I create a table in SQL that allows me to reference the tools by their corresponding integer similar to the way I am already doing it? If it is as simple as copying all the data into a table and then referencing it with a slightly different function, then I apologize for the simple question, and a simple answer would still be welcomed!

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Apparently I didn't give myself enough credit. I already have a table created within a database through SQL Server Management Studio. This table just has two columns, `number` and `name`. If this is wrong, then I was asking what I need to do to change or fix it, and then if this is correct, I just want to know what I need to do within Visual Studio in order to reference these tools just like I can with the dictionary. Is it really as simple as importing the database and then referencing it with `db.Tools.[number]` or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend googling some entity framework turorials, particular Code First.

When you learn how to create models, this would be a good starting point for your model:

```
class Tool { 
  int ToolId {get;set;}  
  string Name {get;set;}
}
```

To grab a specific tool

```
Tool myTool = db.Tools.Single(t=>t.ToolId == theVariableWithToolIdIWant);
string theNameOfTheTool = myTool.Name;
```

This won't make much sense at the moment, but after you go through some tutorials and setup your database context, hopefully it will help give you a jump start on what you want to do.

Comment: I think this can help me, but I should have made it more clear in my question, but I already have a Table in an SQL Database with one column for the numbers and another column for the names. I just was wanting to know if there was a simple way to call these instead of a calling from the dictionary. Is this still what you answer will do? If so, thanks a lot!

Comment: In that case I'd use the EF database first approach since you have an existing database. The second line of code still applies.  `db` is your ObjectContext, and .Single is still used to grab a specific Tool with a desired id.

Comment: Ok thanks! I this looks like it should be as easy as I thought it should be. I'll come back and accept the answer if I get everything to work.

Comment: I have everything set up, but how can I output the string associated with the integer that I put in? That's what my dictionary was doing, and I would like to just input an integer and get the string name associated with that integer.

Comment: @VarnerBeast14 If your column with the string is called `Name` then it is a property on the Tool entity.  I have added another line of code demonstrating.